# In Snowflake which of the following objects can be cloned?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

In Snowflake Which of the following objects can be cloned?
A. Tables
B. Named File Formats
C. Schemas
D. Shares
E. Databases
F. Users

Tables, Schemas and Databases I know but can we also clone Users or Named File Format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Snowflake, the following objects can be cloned:

- Data Containment Objects

  - Databases
  - Schemas
  - Tables
  - Streams
- Data Configuration and Transformation Objects

  - Stages (external only - not internal)
  - File Formats
  - Sequences
  - Tasks

The following account level objects cannot be cloned:

- Users
- Roles
- Grants
- Virtual Warehouses
- Resource monitors
- Storage integrations

Comment: Thanks Robert.. You are really gem ..You made my questions so simple to understand

Comment: You're welcome. Happy that it helps !

Comment: @RobertLong Can we clone the pipe object only?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly clone DATABASE, SCHEMA, TABLE, STREAM, STAGE,  FILE FORMAT,  SEQUENCE, and TASK objects:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-clone.html#syntax

Comment: Hi Greg.. But how about Named File Format can it be cloned??

Comment: Also how about Users..Can it be cloned?